# UITextField keyboard blocks runloop while loading?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Because I'm finding the annoying problem of a really long first load time for the keyboard (even with iphone4S ios 5), I'm trying to implement a custom UITextField that shows a UIActivityIndicator if the keyboard is taking too long to load. However, I'm finding that the UIActivityIndicator cannot be added to the superview while the keyboard is loading. Either the activity indicator shows up way too soon if I set a shorter delay, or the indicator shows up way too late, as the keyboard is appearing, when I set a slightly longer delay (0.3 ms, though in actuality takes like 1+ seconds, as the keyboard loads).

I've tried setting up my activity indicator using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes: in NSRunLoopCommonModes but it seems the keyboard loading blocks this mode. I've also tried using GCD, but it seems I run into the same problem of having to do the activity indicator setup in the same dispatch queue as the keyboard loading and displaying. How can I add an activity indicator view while the keyboard is loading? Here is my code:

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
    CGPoint spinnerCenter;
    BOOL shouldShowSpinner;    
}
@property (assign) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
@property (assign) CGPoint spinnerCenter;
@property (assign) BOOL shouldShowSpinner;
- (void)stopSpinner;
@end


@implementation CustomTextField

@synthesize spinner;
@synthesize spinnerCenter;
@synthesize shouldShowSpinner;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.spinnerCenter = self.frame.origin;
        self.spinner = nil;
        shouldShowSpinner = NO;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(stopSpinner) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)stopSpinner
{
    shouldShowSpinner = NO;
    if (spinner != nil) {
        [spinner removeFromSuperview];
        spinner = nil;
    }
}


- (void)loadSpinner
{
    if (shouldShowSpinner) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(spinnerCenter.x - 15, spinnerCenter.y - 15, 30, 30);
        self.spinner = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:rect] autorelease];
        [spinner startAnimating];
        [theSuperview addSubview:spinner];
    }
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event] && self.hidden == NO && self.isEditing == NO) {
        shouldShowSpinner = YES;

        // the GCD approach, have to be stuck on current dispatch queue?
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 300000000), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
            if (shouldShowSpinner) {
                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(spinnerCenter.x - 15, spinnerCenter.y - 15, 30, 30);
                self.spinner = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:rect] autorelease];
                [spinner startAnimating];
                [theSuperview addSubview:spinner];
            }
        });

        // The NSRunLoopApproach, NSRunLoopCommonModes blocked by keyboard loading?
        [self performSelector:@selector(loadSpinner) 
                   withObject:nil 
                   afterDelay:0.3 
                      inModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Surely there is some other issue in your code if the keyboard is taking so long to long that it warrants an activity indicator.

Comment: Well I'm actually using UITextField in conjunction with cocos2d. Didn't think this would be an issue. Is this an issue? I'm not loading any major textures or spritesheets, just using the default.png for background as a test.

Comment: Did you tried a build NOT in Debug mode? Due to the optimization level: ```Fastest, Smallest [-Os]``` it could improve the speed. You can change it on ```Build Settings > Optimization Level```

Comment: @richard -- did you ever find out what this problem was? I'm getting a very long delay before my text field becomes active. I can't tap anywhere else for like 10-15 seconds. Once I get the blinking caret, then everything is easily tappable, no further problems. But the "first click" really stinks. Any solutions?