# iPad iOS 9 having issue in display keyboard when select textfield

Tags: objective-c, ios9

My app is iPhone based app , while running my application in iPad device 
I select the UITextField, It takes 10 to 20 secs to display the keyboard for the first time  in the iPad device alone,but later it working fine in displaying keyboard, Its a strange thing,

Please help me to get rid of this problem

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357026/super-slow-lag-delay-on-initial-keyboard-animation-of-uitextfield

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    // Preloads keyboard so there's no lag on initial keyboard appearance.
    UITextField *lagFreeField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:lagFreeField];
    [lagFreeField becomeFirstResponder];
    [lagFreeField resignFirstResponder];
    [lagFreeField removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Taken from this stack overflow answer: [Super slow lag/delay on initial keyboard animation of UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357026/super-slow-lag-delay-on-initial-keyboard-animation-of-uitextfield)

Comment: From what I've read elsewhere it seems to be an issue in debug mode when launching the first time due to the optimization settings in your build settings. Fastest, Smallest [-Os]. I would double check if you still see the issue when building in release mode. If you don't then you could wrap the preloading code in an #ifdef DEBUG so it will only be added when you're running in debug mode for convenience. A 10-20 second delay is longer than I was experiencing. I was only seeing around 5-7 second delays.