# Why is a modal Segue taking more than 4 seconds to present a new ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, transition

I am using IOS 9.0 and swift, and Xcode 7.1.1, and I am just doing something extremely basic, which is using a Segue in Interface Builder to show a new ViewController when a button is touched on the presenting view controller. And when i run the app on my iPhone, it takes just a little about 4 seconds for the transition to occur. Below are the options i chose for the Segue. I turned off "animation" because with animation the transition was even slower. So how can one control the speed of transition in Interface Builder or programmatically. This transition time is unacceptable, has anyone run into this?

[image]

Comment: What VC is being presented? Is it slow to initialize? Have you tried using Instruments to see where the time is spent?

Comment: is there any code that we should be concerned about in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods of the modal VC? if somethings takes long to execute in those methods they will block the VC from showing until completed, like a webservice call that isnt asynchronous or something

Comment: Did you try with the cable disconnected and does the problem go away? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357026/super-slow-lag-delay-on-initial-keyboard-animation-of-uitextfield

Answer (score 1):

Can you delete all things inside `viewDidLoad` , `viewWillAppear`, `prepareForSeque` of your destinated ViewController?

It isn't slow because of `Animation` or `Speed of transaction`. The problem is inside your code.

Comment: Also, present a different, simpler view controller and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, the problem must have been inside my code. I created a dummy project to test how fast the segue between two viewControllers that had no subviews would occur and the transition was immediate, so the problem must have been in my code. I decided to start my project from scratch and now the segue works fine.  In the old project,  I started it with a  "Game" template because part of my app will use SpriteKit, but I had not yet created any SKScenes. I am not sure if that was the issue. I started this new project as a single View and things a working fine now.