# iPhone virtual keyboard popup slow on UITextField click

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

It takes 2-3 seconds for the keyboard to pop up after I touch my UITextField.

I tried :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Preloads keyboard so there's no lag on initial keyboard appearance.
  UITextField *lagFreeField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
  [self.window addSubview:lagFreeField];
  [lagFreeField becomeFirstResponder];
  [lagFreeField resignFirstResponder];
  [lagFreeField removeFromSuperview];
}
```

which seems to be working when i searched [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357026/super-slow-lag-delay-on-initial-keyboard-animation-of-uitextfield).But this isn't working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you comment out last two lines?

Comment: trying in real device or simulator ?@Jas

Comment: tried in both iPad and simulator

Comment: @Jas every time you are facing this problem ?. or only for first time ?