# Very slow opening of UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have two VCs. One as navigationController, and other as modal view. 
I am using segue to show modal view.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openFilterSegue", sender: nil)
});
```

and opening something like this

```
class FilterVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, AlertMessage {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pickerLabel.text = arrShopCentrum[row].nazev
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15) 
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return arrPlace.count
  }
}
```

when I am opening that VC for the 1st time it takes about 3 SECONDS to load. Then I close it and it will open quicker.

BTW I am using there a `REALM` object DB but I think that is not the problem.
Its in storyboards and Delegate + datasource are connected

Comment: Have you used instruments to see what's taking so long?

Comment: Hi, I think you forgot to super call of viewDidLoad method in FilterVC.

Comment: I called  super.viewdidload. Nothing improve.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez: I Think for 80% thats Pickerview. There is no auto layout collision or something else.

Comment: What are the results exactly from Instruments?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same issue for quite some time now. It seems to be bug while connected to Xcode.

Other instances of this bug can be found here:

- [Instance 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357026/super-slow-lag-delay-on-initial-keyboard-animation-of-uitextfield)
- [Instance 2](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/slow-initial-responsiveness-in-keyboard-while-device-is-connected-to-xcode.1792646/)

Best of luck!

Comment: I may very well be incorrect in assuming this is simply a bug with Xcode. However, if it is just slow performance due to Xcode being inefficient, there's not really much I can do in terms of advice, aside from letting you know that you're not alone in experiencing this issue which is what my answer attempts to do.

Comment: But its not inside Xcode. But in real device running iOS 8.4 and 9.2.1 :-/

Comment: Does it still take a long time to show the Picker after you've installed the application, unplugged the device from your computer, restarted, and re-ran the application?

Comment: well yes. Thats my issue. :-)

Comment: If this really is the case, then I would be incorrect in assuming its a bug from Xcode. This sounds more like a leak in my opinion.